# Website to android app approach

Tags: java, android, ios, native, porting

I'm a newbie android developer and we have a website that sells some stuff (using a payment gateway), you can also login on the site using credentials, facebook, or google+ login. Now we have a need for an android and iOS app. What is the best approach to port the site functionalities to Android or iOS app? What are the issues I need to consider when I choose one approach? What would be the best approach: native, hybrid (phonegap, xamarine etc.) or using wrapped (using webview as far as I know)? I'm especially interested in the user login part (because I want the user to be able to login to his account if it exists and if not to create it using the website API endpoint - this is how I imagine it), how to solve that when choosing between these approaches? Any suggestions (answers, comments, links, books) would be helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

My sugestion is to do native, always can reach more performance in multi thread ,high concurrency transactions and heavy applications.

For android, you can build from source an application, and export the html/css content to the smartphone using android.webkit.WebView. Take a look:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html

I think is a excellent solution for your problem.